# The geodesic differential equations in an orthogonal coordinate system

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Prove that for an orthogonal coordinate system the geodesic differential equations become
$$\frac{d}{ds}[g_{ii}(\frac{dx^i}{ds})]=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{j=1}^{n}\frac{\partial g_{jj}}{\partial x^i}(\frac{dx^j}{ds})^2$$

My idea to solve this problem is to start from the general equation of geodesics
$$\frac{d^2(x^k\circ \gamma)}{dt^2}+\sum_{i,j=1}^{n}\Gamma_{ij}^k\circ \gamma \frac{d(x^i\circ \gamma)}{dt}\frac{d(x^j\circ\gamma)}{dt}=0$$
Using that
$$\Gamma_{ij}^k=\frac{1}{2}g^{km}(\frac{\partial g_{mi}}{\partial x^j}+\frac{\partial g_{mj}}{\partial x^i}-\frac{\partial g_{ij}}{\partial x^m})$$
Since it is an orthogonal coordinate system I know that $g_{ij}=g_{ji}=0$ as long as i and j are different.
I have tried to solve this in the geodesic equation to get to the solution but the composition with $\gamma$ makes it difficult for me and I have tried omitting it but still I do not get where I want.

I have also tried to make the derivative of the expression of the statement to see if I arrive at the same thing as clearing the Christoffel symbols in the geodesic equation but I have not come to anything. I would appreciate if someone could explain and help me to do the exercise.

Comment: A quicker method is to recall the geodesic equation is the vanishing of first variation of energy, i.e., the Euler-Lagrange equation for the energy functional $E[c]=\int g(\dot{c},\dot{c})$..

Comment: I would like to know how to do it the way I enunciate because it is how I have thought about it from the beginning but I do not know how to move forward

Comment: What do you call an orthogonal coordinate system?

Comment: @Didier OP said that $g_{ij} =0$ when $i\ne j$.

Comment: Exactly for this reason, when I make the chistoffel symbols I only have the $g_{ii}$ and the $g_{jj}$ but I also have the $g ^{ki}$ and the $g ^ {kj}$ and I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: I think there might be a notational inconsistency between the two geodesic equations. The $x^i$s in the first equation seem to be component functions of the curve $\gamma$, but in the second they are coordinate functions. In other words, it seems that $x^i$ in the first equation is the same as $x^i\circ\gamma$ in the second equation.

Comment: Introduce some notation: $g_{ij} = \lambda_i\delta_{ij}$. Then $g^{ij} = \lambda_i^{-1}\delta^{ij}$ and
$$ g^i_k = g^{ij}g_{jk} = \lambda^{-1}_i\lambda_k\delta^{ij}\delta_{jk} = \frac{\lambda_k}{\lambda_i}\delta^i_k $$
Now just put this all into the general equation for a geodesic.